# Oracle SQL command for HAVING COUNT

Tags: sql, oracle

The question is

> The details of any works of art along with the full name of the Artist who created the work that have at least two copies recorded in the database.

I tried using this code but it showed nothing:

```sql
SELECT w.WorkID, w.Title, w.Copy, w.Medium, w.Description,
       a.FirstName || ' ' || a.LastName AS ArtistFullName
FROM dtoohey.Work w,
     dtoohey.artist a
WHERE w.ArtistID = a.ArtistID
AND w.WorkID IN (
        SELECT w.WorkID
        FROM dtoohey.Work w
        GROUP BY w.WorkID
        HAVING COUNT(w.copy) > 2
        );
```

I'm very confused on what to add or change for `having count`.

The data shows the copy as in the picture below.

[the data shown of the 'copy'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwTIo.png)

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: I _guess_ that it should be `having count(case when copy <> 'Unique' then 1 end) >= 2`.

Comment: Don't re-use a table alias in the same query. (It's too easy to make mistakes if you do.)

Comment: Please post a data model (table and their references) and sample data ast plain text. What does "have at least two copies" mean in general words?

Answer (score 3):

You need to analyse your data and work out what is going to be the same for the copies. If `WorkID` is a primary key then there will only ever be one row with that identifier; in that case, you need to use some other method of detecting copies such as the combination of `Title` and `ArtistID`.

Additionally, `HAVING COUNT(w.copy) > 2` will check to see if there are three-or-more copies. You want either `> 1` or `>= 2` to check for two-or-more copies.

```sql
SELECT w.WorkID,
       w.Title,
       w.Copy,
       w.Medium,
       w.Description,
       a.FirstName ||' '|| a.LastName AS ArtistFullName
FROM   dtoohey.Work w
       INNER JOIN dtoohey.artist a
       ON w.ArtistID=a.ArtistID
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   dtoohey.Work x
         WHERE  x.artistid = w.artistid
         AND    x.title    = w.title
         GROUP BY x.artistid, x.title
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       );
```

You could also use analytic functions to count the duplicates:

```sql
SELECT w.WorkID,
       w.Title,
       w.Copy,
       w.Medium,
       w.Description,
       a.FirstName ||' '|| a.LastName AS ArtistFullName
FROM   ( SELECT w.*,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY artistid, title) AS cnt
         FROM   dtoohey.Work w
       ) w
       INNER JOIN dtoohey.artist a
       ON w.ArtistID=a.ArtistID AND cnt > 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dtooney.work (workid, title, copy, medium, description, artistid) AS
SELECT 1, 'Finger Painting', '1/5', 'Acrylic on Paper', 'Finger Painting', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Finger Painting', '4/5', 'Acrylic on Paper', 'Finger Painting', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'The Scream', '1/1', 'Wool', 'Knitted version of The Scream', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Half a Cow', '1/2', 'Taxidermy', 'Front Half', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Half a Cow', '2/2', 'Taxidermy', 'Left Half', 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE dtooney.artist (artistid, firstname, lastname) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', 'Abbot' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Betty', 'Baron' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol', 'Count' FROM DUAL;
```

Both outputs:

| WORKID | TITLE | COPY | MEDIUM | DESCRIPTION | ARTISTFULLNAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Finger Painting | 1/5 | Acrylic on Paper | Finger Painting | Alice Abbot |
| 2 | Finger Painting | 4/5 | Acrylic on Paper | Finger Painting | Alice Abbot |
| 4 | Half a Cow | 1/2 | Taxidermy | Front Half | Carol Count |
| 5 | Half a Cow | 2/2 | Taxidermy | Left Half | Carol Count |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6oiqJZmr)